# How to get list of related objects in Django-rest-Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to implement Nested serializer for the first time in django-rest-framework
My requirement is i need the response data in below form :-

```
{
id: 0,
title: "Fresh",
data: [
    [{
            image: ".../assets/images/banana.jpeg",
            name: "Fruits",
            image_scaling: 2,
            API: "http://database_api"
        },
        {
            image: "../assets/images/banana.jpeg",
            name: "Vegetables",
            image_scaling: 2,
            API: "http://database_api"
        },
        {
            image: "../assets/images/banana.jpeg",
            name: "Exotic Vegetables",
            image_scaling: 2,
            API: "http://database_api"
        }
    ]
]

}
```

I am validating the token for the get api and listing the objects form DB.
My current implementation of views.py is :-

```
class home(APIView):

 def get(self,request,format=None):

    header_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
    if header_token is not None:

        token = header_token
        access_token=token.split(' ')[1]
        print(access_token)
    
    if(validate_token(access_token) == None):
        raise NotFound('user does exist')
        

    queryset=Fresh.objects.all().select_related('data')
    print(queryset)
    serializer = FreshSerializer(queryset,many=True)
  
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serializer.py is :-

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
    model=data
    fields = ('name','image_scaling','image')

class FreshSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   data=DataSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
   class Meta:
      model = Fresh
      fields = ('title','data')
```

models.py is :-

```
class data(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=9,null=True)
  image_scaling=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True)
  image=models.URLField(max_length = 200)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)

class Fresh(models.Model):
   title=models.CharField(max_length=9)
   data=models.ForeignKey(data,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.title)+" " +str(self.data)
```

My current output is :-

```
[
{
    "title": "vegetable",
    "data": {
        "name": "vegetable",
        "image_scaling": 2,
        "image": "https......jpg"
    }
},
{
    "title": "exoticveg",
    "data": {
        "name": "exoticveg",
        "image_scaling": 2,
        "image": "https://.......jpg"
    }
} ]
```

I was trying to do by listapiview and modelviewset, but i am not able to get the desired output.I have seen similar queries in stack-overflow, but no solution seems to work for me.  I am not getting list of objects of foreign key , am i doing something wrong in my model or running wrong query? I am really stuck at it.
How shall i go about it.
Please help!!!

Comment: The data structure you are attempting to get seems not to represent the data structure of your models, while the data structure you get does. I can see that you set field `data` of serializer `FreshSerializer` as `many=False`, so how can you expect to get a list with several values in field `data`?

Comment: If you could show the data in your models, I would be easier to find your problem.

Comment: @HuLuViCa Data is same as coming in my output

Comment: @HuLuViCa i want to use many =True but it is giving me error data is not callable, because data is currently dictionary , how to pass it as list of objects

Comment: Man, I can't figure out how you expect to have all `data` instances inside one `Fresh` instance. Each `data` instance is related to a different `Fresh` instance, as your current output shows.